# How to I can call a method from another activity with passing data?

Tags: java, android, function, methods

I have 2 activities.
I start one, and at a point I start another one:

```
 Intent enabler = new Intent(this, cprompt.class);
        startActivity(enabler);
```

I want to call a method from the old one, but I want to pass some data too.

This is how I tried:

```
Activity1.sendcommand(DATA);
```

And I got this:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendcommand(String) from the type Activity1
```

And I don't want change the method to static.
The only way if I make a Listener? If I have to, you can describe for me to how?

The java is new for me... :/ But if this problem is solved I think I am done with my program :)

Comment: They say dont call methods from other activities, as they are UI, and if not in front they have no life. define methods in simple classes. use dataStructe to define data and all. learn Android basics it will help in future. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one Activity is active at a time. Are you trying to trigger the method just because you want to pass some data?.You can do it via an `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY", "Data Value");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the `SecondActivity` , you can retrieve the data and process it

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY");
```

It's not just Strings that you can send this way.You can even transmit `Serializable` and `Parcelable` Extras. For more information refer - [Intents on Android Developer Website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: I solved, but because I have a little experience in OOP, especially in JAVA I thought I can solve if I just call a method and pass a data in it and do what I want the method will return, but now I know if this method be in another activity I can't do this... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an `interface` and make `Activity1` **implements** that interface..
Then when you need to call Activity1's method call the inetrface's method...

Your interface:

```
public interface OnSendCommand{
    public void onSendCommand(values);
}
```

Activity1:

```
public Activity1 implements OnSendCommand {
    public void onSendCommand(values){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning to the first activity from the second when executing this method? If so you could use startActivityForResult() following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) tutorial. If not, then something is wrong with the structure of your application if this method can not be static, and this method should be in a separate class not inheriting from Activity.